# Page will not center in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

When putting someones old javascript function on my page it makes it no longer center in IE(7).  What I think is causing it is the page width is getting superficially longer as a result of the script.

This is how I have it centered:

```
#container{width:960px; margin:0 auto;}
```

Here is what I have tried to fix it (needless to say it didnt work):

```
 if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1) {
  document.getElementByID("container").style.marginLeft=(((document.body.offsetWidth - 960)/2));
 }
```

Thank you ahead of time! :-)

Comment: The source code of that site is so flawed, it's painful to read :( Where is the DOCTYPE? Did you hear about putting JavaScript code at the bottom of the document? The reason your fix does not work is because you try to get the container element before it has even been parsed... You introduced over 30 global properties just in the inline JavaScript code. Try putting that code trough JSLint, you will get tons of errors.

Comment: ouch :-).  Lol its not a published site yet.  Please read the post carefully before flaming.  The client asked me to use SOMEONE ELSES JS code in this website.  As a quick fix for some issues caused by this (terrible) code, I removed the Doctype.  I know its painful to read, but at the top of the JS there is a comment saying that it is 7 years old and giving the authors name (notice its not me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet explorer has had problems with margin:0 auto since the dawn of its creation. Its very picky.

Take a look at number 6 on this article and try that

http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/internet-explorer.shtml

Comment: The "bug" occures on IE9 too, it's his scripts which mess up the layout (have you seen the scrollbars ?!)

Comment: Actually, it's just the missing DOCTYPE that's causing the OP's problem.

Comment: The missing DOCTYPE must be why this is the only page in the site with this problem.  I removed it because it was breaking that awful JS I have to use.  body {text-align:center} did however work! Thank you for the article.

Comment: @MatTheCat good eye! i think I can remove the scrollbar, just havent looked into it yet.

Comment: didnt even look at the doctype, good catch. Always something to look for when IE is acting weird. Its notorious for being stupid with doctype irregularities

Comment: I am curious to know how a doctype was breaking JS tho

Answer (score 3):

Totally agree with the posts above, had a lot of problems with IE before specifying a DOCTYPE, e.g.: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`

Comment: Why not just <!DOCTYPE html> ?

Comment: b/c I am not using any features of html5? And all the other pages are xhtml.

Comment: Are you validating against the dtd? HTML 4 strict mode is quite actually picky about its markup and order. And you don't need html5 features to use that doctype.

Comment: 5 years later I stumbled across this again. `<!DOCTYPE html>` for the win!